# What do I need to have in my sln file in order to use a API controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, datatables, json.net

I have an MVC webapp to which I have added an API controller to, however I am having trouble accessing and using the api controller.

My code is based on a sln file I downloaded runs properly with live demos here -- https://editor.datatables.net/download/index
I am using the .NET edition

I have tried to replicate what this sln file does.  The jquery front end calls on a API controller and it receives json to format into a table.

I have some knowledge in MVC and those files seem to be working properly. 
I am having trouble tracing the problem code.  These are the items I have checked:

- namespaces are correct in the MVC portion
- nuget packages included
- reference files included
- dll is included in references area
- App_Start has a RouteConfig and WebApiConfig file, both of which get registered in the Global.asax.cs

Basically those are all the areas I could think of, what other files in the sln files should I check to make sure the API Controller is accessible?

Comment: I wonder how you went from _"I get an error"_ to _"I think it must be the configuration"_ to _"There's something from with the solution file"_. Did you try reading the error and researching the cause of the actual error?

Comment: Yes it said it would have to do with the MVC files having typos in the namespace, but those should all be clear since they are the same as the files from the working sln file

Comment: I have a Route Config and a WebApiConfig in the App_Start file which both get registered at the global.asx.cs.  Could it be that those two files are conflicting ?

Comment: We really can't tell if you don't show relevant code and exact error messages in your question, so please [edit] it.

Comment: This is the error message I get, Unhandled exception at line 110, column 2 in http://localhost:64485/

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'Editor' of undefined or null reference